# Simple question - represent vector with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Basic question here, I've always been weak at this stuff.

Suppose that we have a situation $U=WX$ where $U,W,X$ are matrices that are known to us. You can suppose that $U$ is invertible.

I want to represent each row vector of $X$ in the basis defined by the rows of $U$. Since $U$ is invertible, this should be possible. And I know that the coordinates we need to find are in the matrix $W^{-1}$ which you can suppose we also know.

All that is well and good in theory, but in practice suppose I want to find the representation of the first row of $X$ in the basis of the rows of $U$. What would it be? would it be the first row of $W^{-1}$? The first column?

Comment: Have you try with SVD ?

Comment: Im just always confused about these things. Could it be that its just the first row of $W^{-1}$?

Comment: I cant answer this question on $W^{-1}$, but I usually, in such cases, exploit SVD method. It makes things more clear and tractable

Answer (score 1):

Given your current problem statement, it is not clear that $W^{-1}$ exists. For example, if $U$ is $n \times n$, then it is possible that $W$ is $n \times k$ and $X$ is $k \times n$, where necessarily $k \geq n$ in order for both sides of the matrix equation $U = WX$ to have full rank. Since transposing the problem converts you from rows into columns, you are essentially trying to solve for a matrix $Z$ (representing the coefficients) such that

$$ X^T = U^T Z$$

Then $Z = (U^T)^{-1} X^T = (XU^{-1})^T = (X^T W^T)^{-1} X^T$.

In the case when you know $W$ is invertible (and hence so is $X$), then this simplifies to $Z = (W^T)^{-1} = (W^{-1})^T$. Therefore the rows of $X$ can be represented in terms of the rows of $U$ using the coefficients from the rows of $W^{-1}$.